# DataTable select criteria with single quotes and without

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have a DataTable **dt** with Column **RefNum**. There is a row with RefNum = 293
when i try to retrieve value using `dt.Select("RefNum = 293")`i get no result , but when i wrap number into single quotes `dt.Select("RefNum = '293'")` i get result

[image]

Could someone explain , how it works ?

other values are fine to read

[image]

in database column **RefNum** is a **nvarchar** column

Comment: Sounds like the data type of RefNum is a string type.

Comment: @Crowcoder RefNum is nvarchar , but so far others values can be read without quotes . How it possible ?

Comment: @Z.R.T. The `nvarchar` is string in SQL.

Comment: @S.Akbari agree , but how some values from the same column can be retrieved without quotes but others can't. How can you explain different behavior on the pic ?

Comment: @Z.R.T. if the behaviour is different, it means the *types* are different. DataTable objects are .NET objects. The column's type will be `string` not `nvarchar`. The comparison will follow *.NET* rules, where comparing objects of different types is `false` by default. In SQL though, one type is implicitly converted into another and the values compared as if they were the same type

Answer (score 0):

It's very weird that you get results on other tables when searching on string values without quotes. Are you certain these are not numeric columns?

According to [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataView_RowFilter)
 and [www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/), filtering on string values/columns requires single quotes.

So I think you better play it safe and use the single quotes.. :-)

Comment: PS: I cannot see your images, they are blocked by my company's firewall.

Comment: those aren't images, it's the Microsoft documentation site. If you can't read the docs, you can't write or *fix* code